Help me to identify this IC marked '840M1D'
Please can anyone help me to identify this IC (840M1D). The IC is driving a transistor before MOSFET on SMPS.


It's an On-Bright OB3840MP PWM controller.


I can't find a confirmed picture, but the marking style matches On-Bright and the pinout is plausible as well.

Thanks a lot for your help Regards
